# What is the best way to space three animations one second apart?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Is there a better way to time these animations one second apart than using `asyncAfter` three times?

```
let firstAnimationTime = DispatchTime.now()
let secondAnimationTime = DispatchTime.now() + 1
let thirdAnimationTime = DispatchTime.now() + 2
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: firstAnimationTime) {
    self.firstAnimation()
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: secondAnimationTime) {
    self.secondAnimation()
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: thirdAnimationTime) {
    self.thirdAnimation()
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, you can use animation with delay, no need of DispatchQueue.

Comment: if your animations are `CABasicAnimations` you can add a delay on the animations

Comment: Please explain what's wrong with your current implementation. Apart from calling `now()` three times, it's pretty good.

Comment: @sharadchauhan thanks. i will look animation delay

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well actually code works perfect but wonder that is there any other method to call animations with 1 second delay. Using three times seems a little awkward.

Comment: you can also use [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622451-animate).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use UIView.animate(withDuration:delay:...)

Maybe even define a function as follows:

```
func animateSequentially(withDurations durations: [TimeInterval], animations: [(() -> Void)]) {

    guard durations.count == animations.count else {
        return
    }

    for index in 0..<animations.count {

        // calculate delay
        let delay: TimeInterval = durations[0..<index].reduce(TimeInterval(0), { delay, duration in
            return delay + duration
        })

        // perform animation
        UIView.animate(withDuration: durations[index],
                       delay: delay,
                       options: [],
                       animations: animations[index],
                       completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And use like this:

```
let myView = UIView()

let durations = [1, 0.5, 1.25]

let animations = [{ myView.backgroundColor = .red },
                  { myView.backgroundColor = .yellow },
                  { myView.backgroundColor = .blue }]

animateSequentially(withDurations: durations, animations: animations)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest / delay like this

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
      // first animation
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
            // second animation
          }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in


         })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create any tool you want to suit your situation but what you have seems already perfect from what you are describing. Look at it this way; the perfect situation is:

```
ToolName.performAt(time, { execution })
```

So in your case `ToolName` can be replaced with `let queue = DispatchQueue.main` and that is done.

But sure you can do something like:

```
    typealias ExecutionClosureType = () -> Void

    func executeInIntervals(intervalDuration: TimeInterval, toExecute closureArray: [ExecutionClosureType]) {
        let now = DispatchTime.now()
        let queue = DispatchQueue.main
        closureArray.enumerated().forEach { (index, closure) in
            queue.asyncAfter(deadline: now + intervalDuration*TimeInterval(index), execute: closure)
        }
    }
```

And then use:

```
    executeInIntervals(intervalDuration: 1.0, toExecute: [
        {
            self.firstAnimation()
        }, 
        {
            self.secondAnimation()
        },
        {
            self.thirdAnimation()
        }
    ])
```

And you should do something like this if this tool is needed.